# Does the order in which RPCs are called match the order they are invoked locally?

Tags: c#, unity, networking

For example:

```
void A()
{
    Debug.Log( "A was called." );
}
void B()
{
    Debug.Log( "B was called." );
}
void C()
{
    NetworkView view = GetComponent<NetworkView>();
    if( view != null )
    {
        view.RPC( "A", specificNetworkPlayer );
        view.RPC( "B", specificNetworkPlayer );
    }
}
```

Is A guaranteed  to be called before B on the "specificNetworkPlayer"'s machine? If not, what is the order, if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkView.RPC.html):

> RPC calls are always guaranteed to be executed in the same order as
>   they are sent

So, yes, it's guaranteed to execute `A` then `B` as your code defines it.

Comment: Is there a slight caveat to this in the case of multiple senders? Eg. I send A B C at the same time as another player sends X Y Z. A third player might receive them in any order, like A B C X Y Z or A X B Y C Z or A X Y Z B C. So the relative order of RPCs from a single client remains identical, but does that guarantee extend to RPCs from multiple players?

Comment: It's true, the order is preserved from the send order. Luckily, I don't see a situation where you'd expect two different clients to send at the same time and expect the order to be preserved on a third client. It would be more reasonable to simply put a method locally that calls `X();Y();Z();` instead of sending each as their own RPC.